# nginx rewrite specific folder to php and arg

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Am trying to redirect
domain.tld/blog/read.php?article=first-article to domain.tld/blog/first-article

What I tried and didn't work resulting in redirect to domain.tld/first-article

```
location "^blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```

```
location /blog {
 rewrite ^/blog/?$ /blog/read.php?article=? last;
 rewrite ^/blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /blog/read.php?article=$1? last;
}
```

```
location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```

Thinking the issue comes from my other parts in the config and mainly second location from below

```
server {
...
...
location ~ "^/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /device.php?name=$1;
}

location ~ "^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /device.php?name=$1&crversion=$2;
}
...
```

Any pointers would help a lot
Cheers

Comment: You have typos in the first `location` block - its missing the `~` operator and a leading `/`. Try: `location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$"`

Comment: I tried also below, and still picks up from _location ~ "^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$"_
```
location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you remove your whole configuration? Yes, regex locations are checked in order of appearance, that `location ~ /blog/...` should be placed **before** `location ~ ^/([^/]+)/...` or it will never have a chance to handle any request at all.

Comment: ahh well that explains it    
I always put it last in config

now works, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fast answer is actually the fact that my config was fine first time, yet nginx config is read top bottom with first match being the one that is used.
So in the end the "fix" was adding the blog part upper in the site config

```
location ~ "^/blog/([^/]+)/?$" {
 try_files /$uri /$uri/ /blog/read.php?article=$1;
}
```